# An interesting integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

$f(x)$ with continuous second derivative on $[0,1]$ satisfies $f(0)=0$,  $f'(0)=0, f(1)=1, f'(1)=3.$
$$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)f'(x) (1+2(f'(x))^2+2f(x)f''(x))dx ?  $$

I found the result of this integral. But I'm looking for different solutions.

Comment: $19/2\,\,\,\,\,$

Comment: Can you please write a detailed solution?

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant but https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28f%28x%29f%27%28x%29+%281%2B2%28f%27%28x%29%29%5E2%2B2f%28x%29f%27%27%28x%29%29%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\int_{0}^{1}f\left( x\right) f^{\prime }\left( x\right) (1+2\left(
f^{\prime }\left( x\right) \right) ^{2}+2f\left( x\right) f^{\prime \prime
}\left( x)\right) dx \\
&=&\int_{0}^{1}f\left( x\right) f^{\prime }\left( x\right)
dx+\int_{0}^{1}f\left( x\right) f^{\prime }\left( x\right) (2\left(
f^{\prime }\left( x\right) \right) ^{2}+2f\left( x\right) f^{\prime \prime
}\left( x)\right) dx \\
&=&I_{1}+I_{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
Let's calculate the first integral.
\begin{eqnarray*}
I_{1} &=&\int_{0}^{1}f\left( x\right) f^{\prime }\left( x\right) dx \\
u &=&f\left( x\right) \ \text{find }du=f^{\prime }\left( x\right) dx
\end{eqnarray*}
Rewrite the given integral using the change of variables.
\begin{eqnarray*}
I_{1} &=&\int_{0}^{1}f\left( x\right) f^{\prime }\left( x\right) dx \\
&=&\int_{f\left( 0\right) }^{f\left( 1\right) }udu \\
&=&\left. \frac{u^{2}}{2}\right\vert _{f\left( 0\right) }^{f\left( 1\right) }
\\
&=&\frac{f^{2}\left( 1\right) -f^{2}\left( 0\right) }{2} \\
&=&\frac{1}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Similarly, the second integral
\begin{eqnarray*}
I_{2} &=&\int_{0}^{1}f\left( x\right) f^{\prime }\left( x\right) \left(
2\left( f^{\prime }\left( x\right) \right) ^{2}+2f\left( x\right) f^{\prime
\prime }x)\right) dx \\
u &=&f\left( x\right) f^{\prime }\left( x\right) \ \text{find }du=\left(
\left( f^{\prime }\left( x\right) \right) ^{2}+f\left( x\right) f^{\prime
\prime }x)\right) dx
\end{eqnarray*}
Rewrite the given integral using the change of variables.
\begin{eqnarray*}
I_{2} &=&\int_{0}^{1}f\left( x\right) f^{\prime }\left( x\right) \left(
2\left( f^{\prime }\left( x\right) \right) ^{2}+2f\left( x\right) f^{\prime
\prime }x)\right) dx \\
&=&\int\limits_{f\left( 0\right) f^{\prime }\left( 0\right) }^{f\left(
1\right) f^{\prime }\left( 1\right) }2udu \\
&=&\left. u^{2}\right\vert _{f\left( 0\right) f^{\prime }\left( 0\right)
}^{f\left( 1\right) f^{\prime }\left( 1\right) } \\
&=&\left( f\left( 1\right) f^{\prime }\left( 1\right) \right) ^{2}-\left(
f\left( 0\right) f^{\prime }\left( 0\right) \right) ^{2} \\
&=&9.
\end{eqnarray*}

Thus, from $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\int_{0}^{1}f\left( x\right) f^{\prime }\left( x\right) (1+2\left(
f^{\prime }\left( x\right) \right) ^{2}+2f\left( x\right) f^{\prime \prime
}\left( x)\right) dx \\
&=&\frac{19}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 2):

By the chain rule we have the following identities:

\begin{align}\frac{d}{dx}f(x)f'(x) &= f'(x)^2+f(x)f''(x) \tag{1}\\
\frac{d}{dx}(f(x))^2 &= 2f(x)f'(x) \tag{2}\\
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)^2)\right)^2 &= 2\frac{d}{dx}(f(x))^2\cdot\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(f(x))^2 \tag{3}\end{align}

Hence we can rewrite the integral

\begin{align}&\int_0^1 f(x)f'(x)(1+2(f'(x))^2+2f(x)f''(x))dx \\ &\stackrel{(1)}{=} \int_0^1 f(x)f'(x)(1+2\frac{d}{dx}f(x)f'(x))dx \\ &\stackrel{(2)}{=} \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dx}(f(x))^2(1+\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(f(x))^2)dx \\ &\stackrel{(3)}{=} \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dx}(f(x))^2dx + \frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)^2)\right)^2dx \\ &= \frac{1}{2}(f(1)^2-f(0)^2 + \frac{1}{4}(2f(1)f'(1)-2f(0)f'(0))^2 = \frac{19}{2}\end{align}